# Create new ratio indicator in long data

Tags: r, apply, long-integer

I have a long data frame

```
mydf <- data.frame(
+     date=c("2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-03-01","2016-04-01","2016-05-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-06-01"),
+     value=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
+     country=c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US"),
+     indicator=c("gdp", "gdp", "gdp", "gdp", "gdp", "population", "population", "population", "population", "population"))

         date value country  indicator
1  2016-01-01     1      US        gdp
2  2016-02-01     2      US        gdp
3  2016-03-01     3      US        gdp
4  2016-04-01     4      US        gdp
5  2016-05-01     5      US        gdp
6  2016-02-01     1      US population
7  2016-03-01     2      US population
8  2016-04-01     3      US population
9  2016-05-01     4      US population
10 2016-06-01     5      US population
```

I want to create specific new indicators that come from ratios, e.g. GDP/population*1000

It would look something like this, it has to match the right dates for each respective indicator

```
mydf <- data.frame(
+     date=c("2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-03-01","2016-04-01","2016-05-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-06-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01"),
+     value=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,2,1.5,1.33,1.2),
+     country=c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US"),
+     indicator=c("gdp", "gdp", "gdp", "gdp", "gdp", "population", "population", "population", "population", "population", "gdp per capita", "gdp per capita", "gdp per capita", "gdp per capita"))

         date value country      indicator
1  2016-01-01  1.00      US            gdp
2  2016-02-01  2.00      US            gdp
3  2016-03-01  3.00      US            gdp
4  2016-04-01  4.00      US            gdp
5  2016-05-01  5.00      US            gdp
6  2016-02-01  1.00      US     population
7  2016-03-01  2.00      US     population
8  2016-04-01  3.00      US     population
9  2016-05-01  4.00      US     population
10 2016-06-01  5.00      US     population
11 2016-02-01  2.00      US gdp per capita
12 2016-03-01  1.50      US gdp per capita
13 2016-04-01  1.33      US gdp per capita
14 2016-05-01  1.20      US gdp per capita
```

Is there an easy way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it is easier to make the changes you want with a *tidy* approach using `tidyr` and `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(
         ~date, ~value, ~country,   ~indicator,
  "2016-01-01",      1,     "US",        "gdp",
  "2016-02-01",      2,     "US",        "gdp",
  "2016-03-01",      3,     "AU",        "gdp",
  "2016-04-01",      4,     "US",        "gdp",
  "2016-05-01",      5,     "US",        "gdp",
  "2016-02-01",      1,     "US", "population",
  "2016-03-01",      2,     "AU", "population",
  "2016-04-01",      3,     "US", "population",
  "2016-05-01",      4,     "US", "population",
  "2016-06-01",      5,     "US", "population"
)

df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  spread(indicator, value) %>%
  mutate(`gdp per capita` = gdp / population) %>%
  gather(indicator, value, -c(date, country)) %>%
  drop_na(value)

# # A tibble: 14 x 4
# # Groups:   country [2]
#          date country      indicator    value
#         <chr>   <chr>          <chr>    <dbl>
#  1 2016-01-01      US            gdp 1.000000
#  2 2016-02-01      US            gdp 2.000000
#  3 2016-03-01      AU            gdp 3.000000
#  4 2016-04-01      US            gdp 4.000000
#  5 2016-05-01      US            gdp 5.000000
#  6 2016-02-01      US     population 1.000000
#  7 2016-03-01      AU     population 2.000000
#  8 2016-04-01      US     population 3.000000
#  9 2016-05-01      US     population 4.000000
# 10 2016-06-01      US     population 5.000000
# 11 2016-02-01      US gdp per capita 2.000000
# 12 2016-03-01      AU gdp per capita 1.500000
# 13 2016-04-01      US gdp per capita 1.333333
# 14 2016-05-01      US gdp per capita 1.250000
```

> **N.B.** I've modified the data and added a `group_by` statement to demonstrate the solution with multiple values for `country`.

Comment: Wow this is awesome. May I ask, if I have multiple values for country, where would the code be adjusted?

Comment: @stochastiq, you need to add a `group_by(country)`, I'll edit my answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 2):

Personally I find the reshape package easier to work with, and it automatically handles having multiple countries/however many types of labels/data types you have.

```
library(reshape)
mydf <- data.frame(
date=c("2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-03-01","2016-04-01","2016-05-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01", 
       "2016-06-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01","2016-05-01"),
value=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,2,1.5,1.33,1.2, 2),
country=c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", 'AU'),
indicator=c("gdp", "gdp", "gdp", "gdp", "gdp", "population", "population", "population",
            "population", "population", "gdp per capita", "gdp per capita", "gdp per capita", "gdp per capita", 'gdp'))
```

To get the new indicator, first make your data into wide format so that the relevant columns are next to each other. This is so you can do simple column wise operations

```
df_wide = cast(mydf, date+country~indicator, sum)
```

You want the countries and dates as columns that uniquely define rows (left side of the formula), with differnet indicators as columns (right side of formula)

```
        date country gdp gdp per capita population
1 2016-01-01      US   1           0.00          0
2 2016-02-01      US   2           2.00          1
3 2016-03-01      US   3           1.50          2
4 2016-04-01      US   4           1.33          3
5 2016-05-01      AU   2           0.00          0
6 2016-05-01      US   5           1.20          4
7 2016-06-01      US   0           0.00          5
```

Now make a new column and set this to whatever you want

```
df_wide['g_p_ratio'] = df_wide['gdp'] / df_wide['population']
```

Then use Melt to get this back to your long format

```
df_new = melt(df_wide, id=c('date'))
```

Voila!

```
                       date country value      indicator
gdp              2016-01-01      US  1.00            gdp
gdp.1            2016-02-01      US  2.00            gdp
gdp.2            2016-03-01      US  3.00            gdp
gdp.3            2016-04-01      US  4.00            gdp
gdp.4            2016-05-01      AU  2.00            gdp
gdp.5            2016-05-01      US  5.00            gdp
gdp.6            2016-06-01      US  0.00            gdp
gdp.per.capita   2016-01-01      US  0.00 gdp per capita
gdp.per.capita.1 2016-02-01      US  2.00 gdp per capita
gdp.per.capita.2 2016-03-01      US  1.50 gdp per capita
gdp.per.capita.3 2016-04-01      US  1.33 gdp per capita
gdp.per.capita.4 2016-05-01      AU  0.00 gdp per capita
gdp.per.capita.5 2016-05-01      US  1.20 gdp per capita
gdp.per.capita.6 2016-06-01      US  0.00 gdp per capita
population       2016-01-01      US  0.00     population
population.1     2016-02-01      US  1.00     population
population.2     2016-03-01      US  2.00     population
population.3     2016-04-01      US  3.00     population
population.4     2016-05-01      AU  0.00     population
population.5     2016-05-01      US  4.00     population
population.6     2016-06-01      US  5.00     population
```

You may or may not want your new row labels, but you can fix that

```
rownames(df_new) <- 1:nrow(df_new)
```